# small circled images/icons around HTML text

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, bootstrap-4

Suppose I want to draw a small icon/image left to my HTML code in the webpage as shown in the below wireframe. How can I make this happen? I tried to do this myself but it's not working and rather showing the whole picture above it, whereas I want to display the image in the same row as my h1 heading. Following is the code segment:

```
 div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
    <img class="img-circle" src="download.jpg">
    <h1> A heading </h1>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr> <br>
    <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
  </div>
```

Following is the wireframe of above code:
[A wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KksJx.jpg)

And following is the output:
[But Stack overflow won't let me show :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYZCr.png)

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself? If so please provide code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues are you having? Have you done any research?

Comment: I have included my version of bootstrap code. Please have a look at it and let me know what mistake I'm making if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your images and headlines into their own columns like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://placehold.it/60">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 align-self-center">
                    <h1 class="h3 pl-2">A heading </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr> <br>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, note that the correct class for the rounded images is `rounded-circle`.

And the `align-self-center` class is used to center-align the headline vertically. Finally, the `pl-2` class is used to add "padding-left".

Here's another version that might work even better for you because in this version the image and the headline never stack on top of each other:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2 col-md-3">
                    <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://placehold.it/60">
                </div>
                <div class="col-10 col-md-9 align-self-center">
                    <h1 class="h3 pl-4 pl-md-2">A heading </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr> <br>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice but it still does'nt solve my cause because I want my icon to be displayed in line with my heading, not above it

Comment: Check out the second code snippet I just added. It's designed to do exactly that.

Comment: In the first code snippet, they are stacking on top of each other on small screens only. In the second code snippet, they never stack.

Comment: That's a wonderful effort, but sadly that does'nt work for me as well :(

Comment: Picture is still stacked on the top of heading (like in your first code snippet), and not aligned with it.

Comment: In that case, you either haven't used my exact code snippet OR you are loading an outdated Bootstrap css file. Make sure you load the same Bootstrap css file as I have in my code snippet and copy my code snippet entirely. You can also click the "run code snippet" button above and test it that way. With that second code snippet it will never stack.

Comment: Yes I  was using a slightly different css file, changing it did the job :) but it is only doing work when in small screen not on the larger one, but still good enough

Comment: You can adjust the column classes as needed for larger screens. In that code snippet I only have `col-2 col-md-3` and `col-10 col-md-9` but you can adjust those as needed for larger screens. `col-*` is the class for the smallest screen size.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and show me the snippet as to how can I adjust the column classes for this particular place for a traditional laptop screen? As I'm a total rookie in Bootstrap

Comment: Please post a new question for that so I can earn a few points answering that. :-) Also, in that new question, please explain exactly what you want because right now I'm not too sure what layout you want to produce for larger screens.